# oracle sql query to return rows by eliminate duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle11g, duplicates

I am struck at the below scenario. need your help in modify my query based on the below sample data. My objective is to create a EVENT AND EVENT_LOW using the data available from TEM_GT and TXN table.

**TEM_GT (global temporary table)**

```
est_id primary key, trans_id, trp_id, amount  
  1                   111      2221      1.5   
  2                   111      3332      2.0  
  3                   112      4443      3.0
```

**TXN table**

```
trans_id, trans_type
111          type1  
112          type1
```

**EVENT table**

```
event_id primary key, trans_id,  trans_type, flag.  
   1000                 111         type1      N  
   1001                 112         type1      N
```

**EVENT_LOW table**  (final table)

```
 event_low_id primary key, event_id, est_id, amount.  
    9991                      1000     1       1.5  
    9992                      1000     2       2.0  
    9993                      1001     3       3.0
```

---

```
insert into(event_low_id, event_id, est_id, amount) 
 (
    select event_low_id_s.nextval e.event_id, tg.est_id, tg.amount from
    from   TEM_GT tg, EVENT ee
    WHERE
          tg.trans_id    = e.trans_id   
    AND e.flag           = 'N'
 );
```

Based on TEM_GT and TXN gt, populating data into EVENT table. Now when I try to populate data in the EVENT_LOW table, the above query returns 5 rows instead of 3 rows. This is due to trp_id in TEM_GT table. I do not want to add trp_id in EVENT table, and want to handle the duplicate elimination in the above select query.

I am using Oracle 11g. Please help me on this.

I just build the below sql. It almost resolve my problem. But sometimes it returns different value for the amount column. I wanted my event_low result as below for the est_id **1**.

```
 event_low_id primary key, event_id, est_id, amount.    
    9991                      1000     1       1.5    
    9992                      1000     2       2.0
```

But sometime it returns

```
 event_low_id primary key, event_id, est_id, amount.    
    9991                      1000     1       1.5    
    9992                      1000     2       1.5
```

or

```
 event_low_id primary key, event_id, est_id, amount.    
    9991                      1000     1       2.0    
    9992                      1000     2       2.0
```

---

```
select *  
      from (select x.*,  
                    row_number() over (partition by event_id order by event_id) rn  
              from (seelct e.event_id, tg.est_id, tg.amount  
                           from   TEM_GT tg, EVENT e  
         WHERE  
               tg.trans_id    = e.trans_id     
               AND e.flag           = 'N'  
                    ) x  
            )  
      where rn = 1
```

Any help in tune it further to get exact result . Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your post and format the table design and your sql sample code.

Comment: The information in your question doesn't match the behaviour you are describing. There are more rows in your database that match the SQL than the ones you display above!

Comment: You should check your question cartefully, because it has several errors: TEM_GT: est_id=2 but it is 1 for the corresponding row in EVENT_LOW.   The syntax of the insert is wrong, the table name is missing.   The reason you get 5 rows is probably that you have 2 rows in EVENT with trans_is=111.

Comment: Hi Klas. Yes. You are right. Since EVENT table has 2 rows for trans_is=111 and TEM_GT table also has 2 rows for trans_is=111. I need EVENT_LOW table should have 2 rows for trans_is=111. That is it. So out of 4 rows from the select statement, I need only 2 rows.

Comment: your insert statement won't work. A table name is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first instinct was to use `DISTINCT`. Then I noticed that the duplicates have different `amount`. 
You need to decide which `amount` to use, then apply the appropriate group function.

Example (replace `MAX` and `SUM` if you prefer):

```
select event_low_id_s.nextval e.event_id, MAX(tg.est_id), SUM(tg.amount)
from TEM_GT tg join
     EVENT ee
     on tg.trans_id = e.trans_id   
where e.flag = 'N'
group by e.event_id
```

Comment: Hi Klas, Actually, I need to process all the     **amount**      (in this case for trans_id 111, need to process both 1.5 & 2.0). The above joining not working. Still I am getting 4 rows for event_id-1000.

Comment: Ahh, `est_id` is different as well. I've edited my answer, maybe this is a better match to what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi Klas, I need to process each est_id separately. So my event_low table should have two rows for `est_id` **1** and the **amount** should not be sum up. It should be processed separately. 

     `event_low_id primary key, event_id, est_id, amount.      
        9991                      1000     1       1.5       
        9992                      1000     1       2.0       
        9993                      1001     2       3.0  `

Comment: In that case you should check Gordon Linoff's answer. It seems to be correct. If you get too many rows it is because the database hase more rows that match the SQL than you show in the question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, your sample query should be returning just 3 rows, based on the conditions.

However, the answer to your question is probably to use `select distinct`.  I would also suggest using standard `join` syntax:

```
select distinct event_low_id_s.nextval, e.event_id, tg.est_id, tg.amount
from TEM_GT tg join
     EVENT ee
     on tg.trans_id = e.trans_id   
where e.flag = 'N'
```

Your syntax on the `insert` is incorrect, which suggests that you edited the query, removing the offending part.

Comment: Hi @Gordon-linoff, I have tried your query. Still getting 4 rows for event_id 1000. But need only two rows. Yes.. I have edited my query.

Comment: Hi Gordon, your query giving error `ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here`.